# Simple XMLHttpRequest the response xhttp.responseText; don't work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

this.responseText don't return the content of file. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks
Console.log don't return the content of file.

```
function loadMegaContent() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var mesaj = "";
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

      mesaj = this.responseText

      console.log("-WorkGood-" + this.responseText);

      document.getElementById("logTextWXY").innerHTML = mesaj;

    } else if (this.status == 404) {
      mesaj = "The log don't exist in path";

      document.getElementById("logTextWXY").innerHTML = mesaj;

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/admin/installstatus/fileContent.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
  console.log("--mesaj" + mesaj);

}
```

Error

```
// The message display by console is next:
<title>Session expired</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/Portal"/>
</head><body><p>Session expired please relogin</p></body></html>
```

Comment: We have no way of knowing why that URL is giving that content instead of the content you expect. You’ll need to debug the server-side of things.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to get the content of a file asynchronously, use fetch like:

```
async function loadMegaContent(){
  let response = await fetch("/admin/installstatus/fileContent.txt");
    
  if(response.status==200){
    let data = await response.text();
    console.log("-WorkGood-" + data);
    document.getElementById("logTextWXY").innerHTML = data;
  }else if (response.status==404){
    mesaj = "The log don't exist in path";
    document.getElementById("logTextWXY").innerHTML = mesaj;
  }
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. but, still don't work. The variable messaj return in html the next error "[object Promise]".

Comment: Why would using fetch instead of XHR solve the *session expired* problem?

Comment: I change code with your answer and still display the same error .<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/Portal"/>
</head><body><p>Session expired please relogin</p></body></html>

Comment: @Jonnylonut1098 my best guess is that the session id which is stored as a cookie on your browser is basically saved on the server with an expiry date less than the current date.  I would try restarting my browser and opening a new private window and seeing if it works then.

Comment: @gold-dan thanks for your feedback, but I did the changes and I have  same error.